# I musing tomcat v8.0 with eclipse but unable to register the jdbc drivers with Class.forName()

Tags: java

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        after this line in try block control is going to the catch block with            exception whereas i have added the sql connector in the project library.

Comment: I am listing the exception here

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at com.java.bean.Dao.login(Dao.java:18)

Comment: Please put the exception in the question. There is an edit button on the bottom left of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To use the MySQL JDBC Driver in Tomcat you need to put it into the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder. Otherwise Tomcat does not load it.

Comment: Do i need to make any folder or i can directly copy and paste it inside lib directory

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password =himanshu' at line 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)

Comment: rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from employee where username = " +userName +"and password =" +password );

Comment: error  -> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password =himanshu' at line 1

Comment: @HimanshuRawat you can paste it just in the lib folder
you are missing a blank before the "and" and you should use ' arround the strings
Select * from employee where username = '" +userName +"' and password ='" +password  + "'"

Comment: but you should use PreparedStatements to insert the username and the password into the query.
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username = ? and password =?");
pst.setString(1, userName);
pst.setString(2, password);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: but in oracle when i was writing the query and using " ' " it was showing error.

Comment: THANKS @Pinguin for your precious time

Comment: @HimanshuRawat you're Welcome. If I have helped you, it would be nice if you could upvote my answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: Its going to first line means to prepared statement but not to pst.setString(1, userName)

Comment: PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username = ? and password =?");
  pst.setString(1, userName);
  pst.setString(2, password);